# InvalidRequestException(why:Too many bytes for comparator) in astyanax 1.56.37

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

Refer [InvalidRequestException(why:Too many bytes for comparator) on execute query to composite columns using Asytanax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360067/invalidrequestexceptionwhytoo-many-bytes-for-comparator-on-execute-query-to-c)

I am getting the exact issue using astyanax 1.56.37 and cassandra 1.2.5

I don't see the fix of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4377 working.
Double check : Is this fix present in 1.2.5?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your schema definition and the query that is causing you the problem?

Answer (score 1):

`InvalidRequestException` means there is a mismatch between the composite you are using in `Astyanax` and the way that you've created your `CQL` table.

Quite often this means that you are supplying too many fields for your primary key. With Astyanax you also have to set the CQL version to CQL3 when you are creating your keyspace context.

If you read the details of the JIRA issue you posted, it states that it has been resolved. So yes, this fix is in since the 1.2.0 beta version, so it will be there in 1.2.5 too.

Comment: I am also having similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906147/not-enough-bytes-to-read-value-of-component-using-composite-columns-with-astyana). Can you please take a look. Thanks for the help.